# How to get Safari 12 to process audio from soundcloud?

Tags: ios, macos, safari, soundcloud

Sometime in the last 5 months using soundcloud audio with the WebAudio API in Safari (both iOS and MacOS) seems to have broken. It was working Summer 2018.

I'm wondering if anyone has found a workaround or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Here's a example that plays audio from one of 2 sources. If the source is soundcloud it works on Chrome and Firefox but fails on Safari. If the source is not soundcloud it works on all 3 browsers. The example does not let you switch live so check soundcloud or don't, run it. To try other option click the reload button.

Checking the network headers nothing sticks out. Both sites are setting CORS headers and as pointed it it works in Firefox and Chrome

```js
"use strict";
const log = console.log.bind(console);
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.fillText("click to start", 100, 75);
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', start);
document.querySelector('#reload').addEventListener('click', () => {
  window.location.reload();
});

// Make a audio node
const audio = new Audio();
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
// have something ready to play when the user clicks to start
audio.src = getSilentMP3DataURL();

function objectToSearchString(obj) {
  const parts = Object.entries(obj).filter(v => v[1] !== undefined).map((keyValue) => {
    return keyValue.map(encodeURIComponent).join('=');
  });
  return `?${parts.join('&')}`;
}

// we need to ask soundcloud for a URL for each track as they are temporary
// and encoded by client id
class SoundCloudAPI {
  constructor(clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
  }
  async getMediaURLForTrack(url, options) {
    options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options));
    Object.assign(options, {
      client_id: this.clientId,
      format: 'json',
      '_status_code_map[302]': 200,
    });

    let status;
    let location = "https://api.soundcloud.com" + url + objectToSearchString(options);
    let result;
    let done = false;
    while (!done) {
      log('fetch:', location);
      const req = await fetch(location);
      result = await req.json();
      log('result:', JSON.stringify(result));
      location = result.location;
      status = result.status;
      done = !(status && status.substr(0, 3) === "302" && location)
    }
    return result.stream_url + objectToSearchString({client_id: this.clientId});
  }
}

class OtherSiteAPI {
  constructor() {
  }
  async getMediaURLForTrack() {
    await waitSeconds(1);  // to simulate that we can't set the audio.src immediately when doing soundcloud
    return 'https://twgljs.org/examples/sounds/DOCTOR%20VOX%20-%20Level%20Up.mp3';
  }
}


function waitSeconds(secs) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, secs * 1000);
  });
}

function start() {
  ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click', start);
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', pause);

  const soundcloudElem = document.querySelector('#soundcloud');
  soundcloudElem.disabled = true;
  const useSoundCloud = soundcloudElem.checked;
  const scAPI = useSoundCloud
      ? new SoundCloudAPI('91f71f725804f4915f4cc95f69fff503')
      : new OtherSiteAPI();
  let connected = false;

  // make a Web Audio Context
  const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  const analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  const gainNode = context.createGain();
  analyser.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(context.destination);

  // Make a buffer to receive the audio data
  const numPoints = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  const audioDataArray = new Uint8Array(numPoints);

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    // get the current audio data
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(audioDataArray);

    const width = ctx.canvas.width;
    const height = ctx.canvas.height;
    const size = 5;

    // draw a point every size pixels
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += size) {
      // compute the audio data for this point
      const ndx = x * numPoints / width | 0;
      // get the audio data and make it go from 0 to 1
      const audioValue = audioDataArray[ndx] / 255;
      // draw a rect size by size big
      const y = audioValue * height;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }

    ctx.fillText('click to pause/play', 20, 20);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);


  audio.play();

  scAPI.getMediaURLForTrack('/resolve', {url: 'https://soundcloud.com/chibi-tech/lolitazia-season'})
    .then((url) => {
      // this line is only needed if the music you are trying to play is on a
      // different server than the page trying to play it.
      // It asks the server for permission to use the music. If the server says "no"
      // then you will not be able to play the music
      // Note if you are using music from the same domain
      // **YOU MUST REMOVE THIS LINE** or your server must give permission.
      log('set audio.src:', url);
      audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
      audio.src = url;
      audio.load();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      if (error.stack) {
        console.error(error.stack);
      }
    });

  // call `handleCanplay` when it music can be played
  audio.addEventListener('canplay', handleCanplay);

  function handleCanplay() {
    // connect the audio element to the analyser node and the analyser node
    // to the main Web Audio context
    if (!connected) {
      log('connect media');
      connected = true;
      const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      source.connect(analyser);
    }
  }

  function pause() {
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
    } else {
      audio.pause();
    }
  }
}


function getSilentMP3DataURL() {
  return "data:audio/mp3;base64,SUQzBAAAAAAAI1RTU0UAAAAPAAADTGF2ZjU2LjM2LjEwMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//OEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASW5mbwAAAA8AAAAEAAABIADAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV1dXV6urq6urq6urq6urq6urq6urq6urq6urq6v////////////////////////////////8AAAAATGF2YzU2LjQxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJAAAAAAAAAAAASDs90hvAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA//MUZAAAAAGkAAAAAAAAA0gAAAAATEFN//MUZAMAAAGkAAAAAAAAA0gAAAAARTMu//MUZAYAAAGkAAAAAAAAA0gAAAAAOTku//MUZAkAAAGkAAAAAAAAA0gAAAAANVVV";

}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; display: block; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="soundcloud" checked type="checkbox">: Use SoundCloud
  <button id="reload" type="button">reload page</button>
</div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: note: As of July 2021 Soundcloud changed their APIs. A server is now required to negotiate between the soundcloud API and the webpage. There's an example [here](https://github.com/greggman/soundcloud-audio-reactive-example)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with streaming in an HTML AudioContext from SoundCloud on Safari. The problem seems to be the redirecting from the SoundCloud API to actual audio file. The following workaround works for me:

```js
const response = await fetch(`${track.stream_url}?client_id=${Helper.SOUNDCLOUD_CLIENT_ID}`, {
  method: 'HEAD'
});
return response.url;
```

The snippet does a HTTP HEAD request on the API resource, follows the redirect and returns the redirect URL, which can be used on an Audio element. I use it with an sound analyser to display some sound visualization.

Answer (score 0):

That indeed sounds like a weird Safari bug, and you may want to let them know about it.

For a workaround, you can simply avoid the long road *Media -> MediaElement -> MediaStream -> Web Audio* here by doing directly *Media -> Web Audio*.

First fetch your media as an ArrayBuffer, then decode the Audio data from this media and play it using an AudioBufferSourceNode.

```js
"use strict";
const log = console.log.bind(console);
const ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx.fillText("click to start", 100, 75);
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', start);


function objectToSearchString(obj) {
  const parts = Object.entries(obj).filter(v => v[1] !== undefined).map((keyValue) => {
    return keyValue.map(encodeURIComponent).join('=');
  });
  return `?${parts.join('&')}`;
}

// we need to ask soundcloud for a URL for each track as they are temporary
// and encoded by client id
class SoundCloudAPI {
  constructor(clientId) {
    this.clientId = clientId;
  }
  async getMediaURLForTrack(url, options) {
    options = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(options));
    Object.assign(options, {
      client_id: this.clientId,
      format: 'json',
      '_status_code_map[302]': 200,
    });

    let status;
    let location = "https://api.soundcloud.com" + url + objectToSearchString(options);
    let result;
    let done = false;
    while (!done) {
      log('fetch:', location);
      const req = await fetch(location);
      result = await req.json();
      log('result:', JSON.stringify(result));
      location = result.location;
      status = result.status;
      done = !(status && status.substr(0, 3) === "302" && location)
    }
    return result.stream_url + objectToSearchString({client_id: this.clientId});
  }
}

function start() {
  ctx.canvas.removeEventListener('click', start);
  ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', pause);

  const scAPI = new SoundCloudAPI('91f71f725804f4915f4cc95f69fff503')

  // make a Web Audio Context
  const context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
  const analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  const gainNode = context.createGain();
  analyser.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(context.destination);

  // Make a buffer to receive the audio data
  const numPoints = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  const audioDataArray = new Uint8Array(numPoints);

  function render() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(audioDataArray);

    const width = ctx.canvas.width;
    const height = ctx.canvas.height;
    const size = 5;

    // draw a point every size pixels
    for (let x = 0; x < width; x += size) {
      // compute the audio data for this point
      const ndx = x * numPoints / width | 0;
      // get the audio data and make it go from 0 to 1
      const audioValue = audioDataArray[ndx] / 255;
      // draw a rect size by size big
      const y = audioValue * height;
      ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    }

    ctx.fillText('click to pause/play', 20, 20);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  scAPI.getMediaURLForTrack('/resolve', {url: 'https://soundcloud.com/chibi-tech/lolitazia-season'})
  .then((url) => fetch(url))   // fetch our media
  .then(r => r.arrayBuffer()) // as ArrayBuffer
  // and decode it
  .then(buf => context.decodeAudioData(buf))
  .then(audioBuf => {
    // now create an audiobuffer source node
    const source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = audioBuf;
    source.loop = true;
    source.connect(analyser)
    source.start(0);
    return source;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    if (error.stack) {
      console.error(error.stack);
    }
  });
  
  // For pause/play we will pause the entire context,
  // we could also stop the buffer source node 
  //  and start a new one with offset everytime if needed
  function pause() {
    if (context.state === "suspended") {  
      context.resume();
    } else {
      context.suspend();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; display: block; }
```

```html
<!-- Safari doesn't support Promise syntax of decodeAudioData -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/mohayonao/promise-decode-audio-data@eb4b1322113b08614634559bc12e6a8163b9cf0c/build/promise-decode-audio-data.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I'd call your solution the long road. My needs are streaming. Making a user wait 1-10 minutes while a 4 to 120 minute audio downloads kind of defeats the purpose. I did file a bug back when I posted this. Apple marked it with a rdar link so I guess they are aware but they provided no details

Comment: @gman in that case did you check how it behaves with [MSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource)? Since we can apparently fetch without issue, and MediaElements are able to make range requests, there is no reason we can't, and maybe Safari will not experience the same bug. That would though imply that you know the correct codecs before hand, and I don't know SoundCloud API enough to know if they deliver constant formats/codecs.

Comment: Did a quick test, and while I though we were lucky that Safari does support `audio/mpeg` (contrary to FF), it seems their MediaSourceElement is completely broken as it silently fails when the element's source point to an MS...