# Three.js webgl video texture CORS issue on safari

Tags: three.js, safari, cors, webgl, vimeo

In my vuejs nuxt static site hosted on netlify, I'm trying to use a mp4 video hosted on Vimeo Pro as a video texture in three.js with the following (simplified version)

```
// create video dom element
let video_ele = document.createElement('video')
video_ele.className = 'video_texture'
video_ele.setAttribute('playsinline', true)
video_ele.muted = true
video_ele.loop = true
video_ele.autoplay = true
video_ele.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
video_ele.src = "https://vimeo-video-url-here.....mp4"
document.body.appendChild(video_ele)


// create video texture from video
let video_texture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video_ele)
video_texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
video_texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter
video_texture.format = THREE.RGBFormat

// map video texture to material
material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xa8a8a8,
    map: video_texture
})
```

Everything else works fine on chrome, firefox and also chrome mobile browser.
but in Safari 13 on mac os and ios 13, i get this error thrown in the console

```
THREE.WebGLState:
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

I tried replacing the vimeo video with urls of other videos hosted elsewhere and i get same error in safari only.

I'm pretty sure its a CORS issue because when i replace the vimeo or external url with a static video hosted within same host (netlify), it works fine.

I also tried appending a timestamp to the video url just to be sure its not a cache issue, but still no luck

Wondering how can i make this work with an externally hosted video like vimeo?

Comment: This is impossible to test without a paid account to vimeo. In any case Safari doesn't like redirects on media, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886749/how-to-get-safari-12-to-process-audio-from-soundcloud) will work for you. (though it no longer works for me)

Comment: i just realised a few minutes ago that on safari, the expiring 302 redirected url works in safari. but not the original un-redirected url.

Comment: @gman wow the answer from honeymachine worked for me! ill post the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further testing, it seems to me that the issue was caused by the 302 redirect to their CDN that happens when you use a vimeo file url.

As @gman pointed out, there's a similar issue on Soundclound and i found that the solution provided there worked for my case too. 
[How to get Safari 12 to process audio from soundcloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886749/how-to-get-safari-12-to-process-audio-from-soundcloud)

I solved it by making an async fetch request to get the CDN url and then passing it to the video.src. Works in safari mac and ios (13) now  now!

```
  async function getMediaURLForTrack(texture_to_update, passed_url) {
    await fetch(passed_url, {
      method: 'HEAD'
    })
    .then((response) => {
      texture_to_update.src = response.url
    });
  }
```